# How can I get information on element resize event in a Angular 2/Ionic 2 app?

Tags: html, angular, events, resize, ionic2

I need to get information about the size of an element when this element is resized in a Angular 2/Ionic 2 application.

I Already know how to get initial size with ElementRef, but cannot find a way to get information about resizing.

Note that I don't need the size of the window. I need the size of a element.

Comment: What would be triggering the resize? A screen rotation?

Comment: Anything, screen rotation, window resizing (if desktop browser), element resizing via CSS/SCSS (change size using hover, for example), style.width.px data binding on template, etc. Get the size on screen rotation or window resize is not a problem, I already can do this, but on element resize I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas.

First: listen to any event that can trigger a change in the element size. Window size, orientation, hover, etc... then flag it as changed, then check the values of the element.

Second: put whatever element you're looking at in its own component (the child). Use a change detector in that component, and every time it triggers, output an event where you can check the size (or whatever value you want) of that "component" using a viewchild that's looking at the child component element.

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: How could I create a change detector for a component? Is there a Angular  2 change detection API?

Comment: Yes. Check out this article http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html